# viewstate on a custom page with tabs

Tags: viewstate

I am experience some performance issue with my custom page.
I have a custom page which has a tabpanel and each tab includes a page or components. Whenever I update some of fields it sends huge view state (almost 70kb ) to the salesforce and return to the client. Also the ajax response includes all the css js files which are included in the custom page? It takes about 3 seconds to do simple ajax query and 5 seconds to just save one of form in a tab. I already specify some variables to be transient, but is there any way to limit ajax response more? ( for example don't include css,js in response ).

```
<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="{!selectedTab}" value="{!selectedTab}"  id="theTabPanel" >  
    <apex:tab label="Details" name="tabDetails" id="tabDetails" styleClass="subTab" >
       <apex:pageBlock > 
          <apex:include pageName="taskDetailView"/>
       </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:tab>

    <apex:tab label="photos" name="tabPhotos" id="tabPhotos" styleClass="subTab" >                             
       <apex:pageBlock > 
          <apex:include pageName="photos"/>
       </apex:pageBlock>                
    </apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
```

Comment: Have you considered JS Remoting?

Comment: Check out this slide deck:  [7 Habits of Highly Efficient Visualforce Pages](http://www.slideshare.net/developerforce/df121306-ready)

Answer (score 1):

I remember look at your code yesterday and I was going to point it out to you, **minimize the number of forms** on the page because it will be **slow** and you will have **performance issues**.

I have had similar issues in the past and I followed the following [**best practices**](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State) to resolve them. So, at the moment if you are using multiple `<apex:form>` tags in your code, please ensure that you make use of the `<apex:actionRegion>` instead.

Specifying variables to be `Transient` helps but look at other best practices too. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but each page has its own actionFunctions so without apex:form I can't save the page.

Answer (score 1):

OK I decided to include pages dynamically depending on which tab is currently active

```
<apex:include pageName="{!IF((selectedTab=='tabPhotos'),'photos','blank')}"/>
```

Then it doesn't generate view state for photos page but only view state on taskDetailView page. I was hoping the "rendered" attribute works like that. Now response on the ajax call are much faster. Just it has to load the whole page everytime you click on each tab.